# Sub radio button in java

Tags: java, radio-button, wizard

I create a wizard in my plugin to eclipse, and I want to add sub Radio Button to form.
The Primary Radio Button are draw in the `drawDialog()` function:

```
protected void drawDialog(Composite parent){
    //...
    btn1= new Button(Radios, SWT.RADIO);
    btn1.setText(LABEL1);
    btn1.setSelection(true);


    btn2= new Button(Radios, SWT.RADIO);
    btn2.setText(LABEL2);

    btn3= new Button(Radios, SWT.RADIO);
    btn3.setText(LABEL3);

    //...
}
```

and I want to add sub radio button to btn1.
How can I do that?

Comment: what are sub-radio buttons? do you think of an indention for those radio buttons or do you look for something different?